# Design for phone. UX/Service Design

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, service-design

I'm working on a project for which a large part of the target is made up of people who do not use computers. The project involves the delivery. The catalog is available online, for those accustomed to the use of the computer. The catalog is vast (+500), so the paper is very expensive.

Moreover, the problem is how to communicate the choice of products via phone (the only instant communication channel available to the target), in such a way that the operator is facilitated and minimizes errors.
Do you consider it a problem of user experience?

Who do you think should take care of the resolution of this problem? 
A UX Designer, a service designer, a COO or what else?
thank you

Comment: By "phone" are you referring to smartphones or just to the audio-only telephone.  Delivering a 500+ page catalog over  unattended audio would be practically impossible.

Comment: "A UX Designer, a service designer, a COO or what else?" = yes. All of them. And like a CIO, and someone from marketing, and someone from customer service and...at the end of the day, UX should be a company-wide endeavor.

Comment: @HenryTaylor audio-only phone. Really I thought a lot about it but, paper-based solutions aside, I did not come up to a good idea.

Comment: What about services for grocery delivery, like Safeway (http://www.safeway.com/ShopStores/Contact-Us.page#/). How they do this job? it has a lot of products too.

Comment: I don't know about "minimizing errors" but a voice search is the only thing I can really think of which would suit. Add lots of synonyms/related phrases and expect frustrated users.

Comment: What do you mean for "voice search"?

Answer (score 1):

**User Experience Designer role is not always solve a problem but sometimes creating an opportunity**

I do not know the details but it looks like an OEM company is providing products for plumbers and sanitation units. (let me play with some assumptions)

Company does not want to rely on any app or internet solution because of the user group and adoption rate of smartphone and relying on phone for the orders. On field demand important and there are some problems about defining the order and if it is going to be compatible with the other elements.

In these cases, IVR (Interactive Voice Response) solutions can be a solution to minimize the error in communication and creating automated ordering processes. If user can not provide enough detail about the orders, there can be a filtering function before connecting a real support-order unit.

- Is this product made by metal?
- Is this product smaller than 10cm?
- Is thin product black?

These questions (Yes-No, Multiple Choice,0-9 digit) can be generated to make the communication easier and effective.Imagine that you are designing the best help and order system which can be used in Africa. I think that approach can bring you some nice idea and solutions.

**Ok, whose job is it?**

Hiring three guys for saving 10k is not acceptable. Hiring 10 guys for saving 10M is acceptable. You should have an estimation of wasted hours, wrong orders and try to convince C-Level by following some tricks from user centered design. If you can not do that, find a person who can do that for you.

You will need a team that includes **you** and **you can choose who you need**. As in design process, **Reframing** is important while redesigning an existing system or a product. In business level, UX Designers should be able to create dissolvable teams and take more action if they do believe that they can create a value.